# How do I keep dir from matching short file names?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dir

I have a batch file that includes a dir command that is trying to match files that end with a 1.

```
dir *1.*
```

This does not work because dir matches both the short and long versions of file names.  So while MyFileName.ext does not match *1.*, MYFILE~1.EXT does and so MyFileName.ext is included in the results.  How can I prevent dir from matching against short file (8.3) file names?

Comment: the real problem here appears to be distinguishing long from short filenames.  AFAIK, there's no way to do that, if both appear in the same directory listing. There's ways to process each filename using a for loop (FOR /F), but you'd have to have criteria to determine which filenames you wanted to avoid. Do you have such criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - you'll have to match them some other way. Try `dir /b | findstr ".*1\..*"`.